Dynamically changing locationManager (CoreLocation) settings after initialisation
I am currently building a tracking application. I would like to know if the settings of the locationManager can be dynamically changed. I could not find a similar stack overflow question, nor a useful piece of documentation.
Should I do this:
locationManager.distanceFilter = newDistanceFilter
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = newDesiredAccuracy

Or this:
locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
locationManager.distanceFilter = newDistanceFilter
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = newDesiredAccuracy
locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

That is, should the location service be restarted with the new settings, or we can just change the settings and the location manager will automatically use them?

Did you try either option? What was the result?

You do not have to restart your location manager. You just need to set the new values and everything will continue to work.

